# Oslo Masterpage - How to decrease the height of ms-dialogHidden ms-core-header ms-tableRow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page

I want to decrease the height of one of the elements. It's the header. I identified it using IE, as ms-dialogHidden ms-core-header ms-tableRow. I tried setting the height in the css, but nothing happens. It looks like it's fixed. I can manipulate the other elements, but not this one. Image included. Does anyone know how I could change the height of it?

Thanks in advance.

[image]